# how to exclude pages from menu generation with ext:fluid_styled_content?

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, fluid-styled-content

If I define a menu in typoscript I can use `excludeUidList` to exclude some pages.

With CSC if I want my sitemap CE to exclude some pages I could define it at `tt_content.menu.2`.

With FSC the menu-genration moved into the fluid-templates with the usage of the `ce:menu.directory` viewhelper but there I can not find any option to exclude a list of pages (I don't want to have a bunch of `f:if` VHs in the fluid templates to avoid a list of uids)

Comment: What about using VHS? https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Page/MenuViewHelper.html

Comment: It is a shame if existing functionality (existing TS implementation) is dropped while introduing new technics (fluid). Using ext:vhs is an additional dependency I prefer to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use TS and include it to your fluidtemplate with

1. [cObject-Viewhelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/CObjectViewHelper.html). (TYPO3 >= 7.6)

   TS:

   ```
   lib.yourmenu = HMENU
   lib.yourmenu.special = list
   lib.yourmenu.special.value = 35, 56
   ```

   Fluid:

   ```
   <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.yourmenu" />
   ```

Another approuch is to use

2. Fluid data processors. (TYPO3 >= 8.5)
   See [Feature: #78672 - Introduce fluid data processor for menus](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.5/Feature-78672-IntroduceFluidDataProcessorForMenus.html)
   or [TypoScript Reference -> HMENU](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/ContentObjects/Hmenu/Index.html)

   TS:

   ```
   page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
   page.10 {
       dataProcessing {
           10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\MenuProcessor
           10 {
               special = list
               special.value = 35, 56
               as = yourMenu
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Fluid:

   ```
   <ul>
       <f:for each="{yourNav}" as="yourNavItem">
           <li class="{f:if(condition: yourNavItem.active, then:'active')}">
               <a href="{yourNavItem.link}" target="{yourNavItem.target}" title="{yourNavItem.title}">
                   {yourNavItem.title}
               </a>
               <f:if condition="{yourNavItem.children}">
                   <ul>
                       <f:for each="{yourNavItem.children}" as="child">
                           <li class="{f:if(condition: child.active, then:'active')}">
                               <a href="{child.link}" target="{child.target}" title="{child.title}">
                                   {child.title}
                               </a>
                           </li>
                       </f:for>
                   </ul>
               </f:if>
           </li>
       </f:for>
   </ul>
   ```